# Unable to personalize content using tracking key in Target Group?

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, configuration, smarttarget

I have a use case where i want to personalize the content, that a visitor see based on his information saved in Audience Manager (I have added a keyword "personalize" for one of the contact "x"). For this

I have created a a target group, defined its characteristics and tracking keys(defined personalize > 0).

After this, I associated the Target group with a component presentation and Published the Page

When I logged in with "x" credentials I was unable to see that component presentation on the Page.

I have checked the published page and I'mm getting following condition

`<tridion:TargetGroup runat="server" ItemURI="tcm:3-8240-64">
<tridion:Conditions runat="server" Negate="false" Operator="AND">
<tridion:Conditions runat="server" Negate="false" Operator="OR">
<tridion:Conditions runat="server" Negate="false" Operator="AND">
<tridion:Condition runat="server" Type="TrackingKey" Operator="&gt;" Negate="false" Name="personalize" Value="1"/>
</tridion:Conditions>
</tridion:Conditions>
</tridion:Conditions>`

Please Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of Contact Keywords in Target Groups is only used when you send out Mailings. You could still use it on the website, but you would need to write custom code for it that uses a combination of the Audience Manager and P&P API.

As Nuno pointed out, Audience Manager integrates with SmartTarget for the personalization of content on the website.

Answer (score 5):

I'm slightly confused here...

Target Groups and Audience Manager are used for different use cases. Target Groups is for the "lightweight, out-of-the-box" personalization & profiling that comes with every Tridion installation and usually it "just works".

Audience Manager is used to manage segments and (when coupled with SmartTarget) provides a really flexible way to target your audience - but it does not use Target Groups.

I think you need to add code in your presentation layer to read the Audience Manager profile and explicitly `set` the user characteristic for the current user, I don't think Tridion will do this automatically for you (I could be wrong, haven't touched P&P in about 5 years).