# Target Groups based Content

Tags: cme, content-manager

Its mentioned in one of the Post that Target groups are used while sending out the mailings.
[Unable to personalize content using tracking key in Target Group?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/228/unable-to-personalize-content-using-tracking-key-in-target-group)
Is it possible to use Target groups for showing content on Website pages too?

Comment: It depends. Are you looking to create a web version of an e-mail? Or do you just want to show/hide some content on a Page in general? You've tagged this question with SmartTarget - is your question actually related to that?

Comment: If I want to show/hide some content on a Page in general.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. That is the original use case for Target Groups.

To read more about this, have a look at the documentation for "[Target Groups](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B4945556-AD9E-4A19-AB65-D0A63E96D28C)", as well as its parent topic "[Profiling and personalization](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9E40AD8C-D957-40C9-AE71-C5A1A2D6C52C)" (login required for both links)

Comment: Ok I have already read the docs but got confused with the post which I mentioned above. So this means that if I need to target my content based on some User Group I can go with Target groups instead going with Smart Target. And do I need some coding for implementing Target Groups based Content delivery. Or just allowing Targetgroups on Component Presentation will work out?

Comment: You'll need to provide the data that P&P will use to determine whether to show a given Component Presentation. That part _may_ require coding, depending on your use case and where the data comes from.

Comment: Nuno - you mentioned about P&P API.From where I can get this API as I am not able to find it out. Can you tell me the name of this API

Comment: SmartTarget is certainly also an option (particularly if you want your business users to decide what to show to who, as opposed to writing code to do that). But SmartTarget doesn't involve Target Groups.

Comment: P&P is "Profiling and Personalization". The API is all under the com.tridion.personalization package and is a standard part of Tridion Content Delivery

Answer (score 2):

Just to add and summarize the post:-
Minimal feature of customizing which can be achieved from Profiling and Personalization  provided within SDL Tridion Tool itself and no extra licencing fee required.
I tried implementation of personalization through **Target Groups using Custom Characteristics.**
Create Target Group.
Add Target group with a component presentation on the page.
**Note:** Condition will only come after page is published and will not be visible at the time page is previewed. 
Using Target group will lay Tridion conditions tags on the page which is published.
These conditions will be use to Show/Hide component presentation added on the page.
condition will be used by java code through Tridion CD APIs which will use input parameter.
Sample  page will be like :-
`<tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="AND">
<tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="OR">
<tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="AND">
<tridion:Condition type="CustomerCharacteristic" operator="=" negate="false" name="customerType" value="1"/>
<tridion:Condition type="CustomerCharacteristic" operator="=" negate="false" name="customerType" value="0"/>
</tridion:Conditions>
</tridion:Conditions>
</tridion:Conditions>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link explaining about PnP 
http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/how-to-setup-sdl-tridion-profiling-personalisation

Comment: Hi Aman, Can you please comment if above BB link you mentioned for PnP can be used for below scenario or not: 1)Pages have CP Embedded in page, sdl web8 cms 2)on Presentation Server we are using DXA 1.6 to render web pages