# Profiling and personalization Without DCP and tracking keys

Tags: 2013, profiling, personalization

1) Can I use Personalization with Customer Characteristics only? and without Tracking keys? Which means conditions will come from Target group and WAI page will check/Update the Customer Characteristics in broker database and on the basis of that Show Hide the data(CP).

2) Can profiling and personalization  without dynamic presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your first question: Yes. you can use Custom Characteristics without tracking keys.

Second i have never tested but AFAIK it should be published DCP and dropped on page   as Bjorn mentioned in your last post. can't you just try?

Comment: Thanks RAJ for the help.  PnP is working only with Custom Characteristics and DCP is also working.

Answer (score 1):

To start with there are two types of personalization: Implicit and Explicit

Implicit will use Categories and keywords 
Explicit will use Java or .net to set Customer Characteristics using WAI module.
More information can be seen in below post which have full code for my working module.
[Target Groups based Content](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5138/target-groups-based-content/12763#12763)